# can I create a calculation that shows in a pivot table the percent of filter rows?

Tags: powerquery

I created this percent dividing two columns ("Flash"/"Total Orders" for showing in the follow pivot table, the information is correct when I filter in the Market slicer 1 value as the second image. Although, when I select all the Market places I get the sum of all the Market´s percents which is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need that the calculation show the percent = Flash/Total Orders for the filter information in the pivot table without sum it when I filter many Market places for each Business category.

Comment: Remove the calculation from the powerquery and add it as a calculated formula in the pivot table